# R: Filter a dataframe based on another dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics, bioinformatics, tibble

I want to subset `e` df based on `pf` df. The two dataframes share the same rowname. My code adds a "row_names" column, which I don't want.

```
library(dplyr)

e <- e[, !row.names(e) %in% row.names(pf)]


> dput(e[1:10, 1:10])
structure(list(row_names = c("2315374", "2315376", "2315587", 
"2315588", "2315591", "2315595", "2315598", "2315603", "2315604", 
"2315640"), JHU_113_2.CEL = c(6.28274, 5.81678, 8.88557, 6.2865, 
6.97515, 5.94179, 4.9942, 7.67845, 6.20952, 5.85307), JHU_144.CEL = c(6.79161, 
5.71165, 8.95699, 6.6675, 6.61705, 5.39178, 5.56888, 7.90005, 
6.59687, 6.07303), JHU_173.CEL = c(6.11265, 6.02794, 8.36898, 
6.07503, 6.51994, 5.09497, 5.57912, 7.47594, 6.14608, 6.41875
), JHU_176R.CEL = c(6.13997, 5.37082, 8.28993, 6.76625, 6.74982, 
4.96199, 5.4396, 6.75087, 5.70518, 6.07282), JHU_182.CEL = c(6.68056, 
5.95527, 8.41361, 6.19819, 6.60917, 2.96431, 5.19249, 7.62805, 
6.49572, 6.28283), JHU_186.CEL = c(6.48156, 5.75999, 8.6498, 
6.8426, 6.55182, 4.95204, 5.87991, 8.00069, 6.12622, 6.13699), 
    JHU_187.CEL = c(6.45415, 5.87863, 8.74305, 6.13916, 6.6224, 
    5.00979, 5.6054, 7.34296, 6.2369, 6.16377), JHU_188.CEL = c(6.04542, 
    5.5483, 8.31915, 6.40219, 6.44394, 4.06493, 5.09513, 6.81338, 
    6.39569, 6.48616), JHU_203.CEL = c(5.99176, 6.35571, 8.43548, 
    6.45059, 5.76592, 5.38048, 5.43618, 7.52014, 6.70869, 6.34162
    )), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

> dput(pf[1:10, 1:10])
structure(list(JHU_113_2.CEL = c(0.0073, 0.04079, 0.02234, 0.08252, 
0.00127, 0.00256, 0.04265, 0.02244, 0.02615, 0.04563), JHU_144.CEL = c(0.00293, 
0.01525, 0.00914, 0.03644, 0.00162, 0.01274, 0.00798, 0.00955, 
0.00732, 0.02698), JHU_173.CEL = c(0.03034, 0.0309, 0.05024, 
0.09374, 0.00548, 0.04754, 0.03491, 0.03399, 0.02661, 0.01546
), JHU_176R.CEL = c(0.02571, 0.08493, 0.06918, 0.0337, 0.00945, 
0.03185, 0.03182, 0.15281, 0.04117, 0.03758), JHU_182.CEL = c(0.00436, 
0.01303, 0.0521, 0.04909, 0.00341, 0.45759, 0.02033, 0.01911, 
0.01037, 0.01974), JHU_186.CEL = c(0.00788, 0.03559, 0.02822, 
0.02419, 0.00383, 0.02401, 0.00727, 0.0126, 0.01663, 0.02291), 
    JHU_187.CEL = c(0.0052, 0.02163, 0.02401, 0.07845, 0.0028, 
    0.01582, 0.008, 0.0432, 0.01312, 0.03307), JHU_188.CEL = c(0.01704, 
    0.01586, 0.06648, 0.09027, 0.00882, 0.21313, 0.03859, 0.1424, 
    0.01815, 0.01586), JHU_203.CEL = c(0.03273, 0.04264, 0.06823, 
    0.09449, 0.06553, 0.05349, 0.06481, 0.07518, 0.02777, 0.07511
    ), JHU_205.CEL = c(0.0672, 0.05689, 0.1278, 0.12526, 0.03327, 
    0.10091, 0.42112, 0.18431, 0.08595, 0.01157)), row.names = c(2315374L, 
2315376L, 2315587L, 2315588L, 2315591L, 2315595L, 2315598L, 2315603L, 
2315604L, 2315640L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please add the expected output along with your question.

Comment: So just remove the row names afterward? If you want to use `dplyr`, you can't join on row names. You can only join on column values. The tidyverse functions ignore/drop column names in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only wanting to keep the rownames in `e` that occur in `pf` (or that don't occur, then use `!rownames(e)`), then you can just `filter` on the rownames:

```
library(tidyverse)

e %>% 
  filter(rownames(e) %in% rownames(pf))
```

Another possibility is to create a rownames column for both dataframes. Then, we can do the `semi_join` on the rownames (i.e., `rn`). Then, convert the `rn` column back to the rownames.

```
library(tidyverse)

list(e, pf) %>% 
  map(~ .x %>% 
        as.data.frame %>%
        rownames_to_column('rn')) %>% 
  reduce(full_join, by = 'rn') %>%
  column_to_rownames('rn')
```

**Output**

```
        JHU_113_2.CEL JHU_144.CEL JHU_173.CEL JHU_176R.CEL JHU_182.CEL JHU_186.CEL JHU_187.CEL JHU_188.CEL JHU_203.CEL
2315374       6.28274     6.79161     6.11265      6.13997     6.68056     6.48156     6.45415     6.04542     5.99176
2315376       5.81678     5.71165     6.02794      5.37082     5.95527     5.75999     5.87863     5.54830     6.35571
2315587       8.88557     8.95699     8.36898      8.28993     8.41361     8.64980     8.74305     8.31915     8.43548
2315588       6.28650     6.66750     6.07503      6.76625     6.19819     6.84260     6.13916     6.40219     6.45059
2315591       6.97515     6.61705     6.51994      6.74982     6.60917     6.55182     6.62240     6.44394     5.76592
2315595       5.94179     5.39178     5.09497      4.96199     2.96431     4.95204     5.00979     4.06493     5.38048
2315598       4.99420     5.56888     5.57912      5.43960     5.19249     5.87991     5.60540     5.09513     5.43618
2315603       7.67845     7.90005     7.47594      6.75087     7.62805     8.00069     7.34296     6.81338     7.52014
2315604       6.20952     6.59687     6.14608      5.70518     6.49572     6.12622     6.23690     6.39569     6.70869
2315640       5.85307     6.07303     6.41875      6.07282     6.28283     6.13699     6.16377     6.48616     6.34162
```